# PySpark - Split records of an RDD by one or more tabs

Tags: python, apache-spark, split, pyspark, rdd

I have created an RDD from an input file, which looks like this:

```
[u'$, Claw\t\t\t"OnCreativity" (2012)  [Himself]']
[u'$, Homo\t\t\tNykytaiteen museo (1986)  [Himself]  <25>\n\t\t\tSuuri illusioni (1985)  [Guests]  <22>']
[u'$, Steve\t\tE.R. Sluts (2003) (V)  <12>']
```

It is easy to split each record in this RDD based on a tab character, `'\t'`, but what I would like to get is each record splitted based on *one or more* tabs.

I have tried the usual ways of doing that to Python, e.g. when someone wants to split a string based on one or more tabs, but these solutions do not seem to be working in the context of PySpark when trying to split an RDD record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by *a set of RDDs* but it looks like what you need here is a simple regular expression:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\t+")

rdd = sc.parallelize([
    u"foo\t\t\t\tbar",
    u"123\t\t\t456\t\t789\t0"
])

rdd.map(lambda x: pattern.split(x)).collect()

## [[u'foo', u'bar'], [u'123', u'456', u'789', u'0']]
```